# (HTML, CSS) text-align : center is not working on <div>

Tags: html, css

I used text-align:center to center the three divisions, but they are all aligned on the left.
I was told that because these three elements are all block, so they wouldn't center.However, I tried to add display:inline-block, but when I inspected the page, it still showed me display:block.

Here's my code:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      .Google-logo {
        width: 250px;
      }
      .Google-search-box {
        font-size: 13px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        height: 30px;
        width: 460px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgb(160, 157, 157);
        box-shadow: 0 1px 6px rgb(183, 181, 181);
        margin-top: 15px;
      }
      .div {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <img
        class="Google-logo"
        src="images/Google_2015_logo.svg.png"
        alt="Google logo"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input
        class="Google-search-box"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search Google or type a URL"
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="left-button">Google Search</button>
      <button class="right-button">I'm Feeling Lucky</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways, the simplest and the **first way** is to write a CSS like:

```
div { 
text-align: center
}
```

The **second way** if you want to use a inline CSS in your HTML code itself:

```
<div style="text-align:center">
```

The **third way** is what you were trying to do by using classes/id for that you need to change both your HTML and CSS code:

***for class**

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center"> </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.center {
text-align: center,
}
```

***for id**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="center"> </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#center {
text-align: center,
}
```

And most importantly div is not a class it's an HTML tag so your code didn't work because you used

```
.div {

text-align: center,

}
```

in your CSS code and the `.` symbolizes a class whereas if you had written it like this it would have worked as it would have given the text center to all the divs present in your code

```
div {
text-align: center,
}
```

But I feel you should use classes and center the text in div so that it could be specific to the div you wanna center texts for so try to prioritize the second or third way over the first one.

Answer (score 5):

Very simple,

`div` is not a class, is a html element, so do this;

**CSS**

```
 div {
        text-align: center;
      }
```